# How to add new partitions to Amazon Glue table?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue

I have a file structure like so:

```
-year  
   |  
   -month  
     |  
     -day  
        file1  
        file2  
        ...
```

And a corresponding table in Glue with partitions year, month and day

Now I want to add a new partition, say timeofday, so when going forward the structure will look like:

```
-year  
   |  
   -month  
     |  
     -day  
        -am
           file1  
           file2  
           ...
        -pm
           file1  
           file2
           ...
```

I want to know if Glue can handle this from a compatibility perspective?

When I've experimented it seems as the crawler doesn't identify the new partitions and when I add them manually to the table my Athena query breaks with error **Partition value count does not match the partition column count**

Comment: So the S3 structure won't be changed backwards, right? You will just start to use -am and -pm as partition keys from now on.

Comment: Yes that is correct

Answer (score 0):

Here is a few things you may wanna look to solve the issue.

1. If you did changes to your s3 directory structure, you ll need to rerun the crawler once so the changes can take effect.
2. Let's say crawler executed successfully but your table still does not look the way it should. I would look for is the permissions of the IAM role tied with Crawler. A lot of times what happens is, IAM role does not have rights to work on your new directory structure. I delete previous IAM role and created a new with a different name.
3. If you did the above two things and still the issue persists - Delete the table generated by crawler and rerun the crawler.
4. One more thing, make sure when you edit your crawler, do check the following box when you are doing the configurations **Update all new and existing partitions with metadata from the table**

Cheers!!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions but I'm afraid nothing of the above helped. I've reached out to AWS Support.